# Challenge in PostgreSQL query (group by and having issue)

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to create a query but i'm having some trouble with it. I have two tables:

- users (id, name, email)
- comments (id, uid, comment, date, time)

I'm trying to list all users and their comments, which can be done quite easily with an inner join. However, i get various comments per user, since i joined the result. I just want their latest comment. Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 2):

this should do it:

```
select distinct on(u.name, u.id) *
from comments c, users u
where u.id=c.uid
order by u.name, u.id, c.date desc
```

Comment: +1 please upvote this. It makes Postgresql shine compared to other RDBMS

Comment: I didn't know about "distinct on" on Postgresql. Great!

Answer (score 1):

For PostgreSQL 8.4+:

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM (SELECT u.*, c.*,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY u.id 
                                      ORDER BY c.date DESC, c.time DESC) AS rnk
          FROM USERS u
          JOIN COMMENTS c ON c.uid = u.id) x
 WHERE x.rnk = 1
```

Comment: @JavascriptGOD: Yes, it does providing you're using PostgreSQL 8.4+.  What version are you using, and you need to provide more info than "didn't work"

Comment: Nice example of window functions use. Works great.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

EDIT:

I updated the query to this:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.email, t.id, t.uid, t.comment, t.date, t.time
FROM users u
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    select c.id, m.uid, c.comment, m.cdate, c.time
    from comments c
    right outer join 
        (
            select uid, max(date) as cdate
            from comments 
            group by uid
        ) as m
    ON c.cdate = m.cdate
) t
ON u.id = t.uid
```

Comment: I had the same issue and the only way I could get it was with subqueries. maybe someone else can offer up another solution without subqueries.

Comment: Your's didn't worked, unfortunately. :( Missing entry for table c

Comment: Changed table aliases, but this still won't work because there's no date comparison.  Also, this will show duplicates of the latest comment if any exist

Comment: if you run just the subquery does it pull what you need? select c.id, c.uid, c.comment, max(c.date), c.time from comments c group by c.id, c.uid, c.comment, c.time

Comment: @OMG Ponies - pulling the comment by Max(Date) will give you the most recent date entry.

Comment: @OMG Ponies totally busted. I missed part of my original query when I copied it from what I am using.  I updated it now.

Comment: Much better now =)  But still could return duplicates

Comment: not sure how it would be getting dups.  I use this query in a current app and get no dups.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming comment id is autoincrement, find the maximum commentid per user (the latest comment)

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.email, c.id, c.uid, c.comment, c.date, c.time
FROM users u
JOIN comments c ON u.id = c.uid
JOIN 
    (
        select uid, max(id) id
        from comments
        group by uid
    ) as c2 ON c.id = c2.id AND c.uid = c2.uid
```

Answer (score 0):

OMG Ponies certainly has the best answer, but here is another way to do it, without any extended database feature:

```
select

u.name,
c.comment,
c.comment_date_time

from users as u
left join comments as c
on c.uid = u.id
and
c.comment_date_time -
(
    select max(c2.comment_date_time)
    from comments as c2
    where c2.uid = u.id
) = 0
```

I have merge your date and time columns into comment_date_time in this example.